# Clubs and some fixed type is realized by uncountably many elements.

Tags: logic, model-theory, ordinals

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a countable language, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure with
universe $ω_1$.

Let $C$ be the set of countable ordinals $α$ such that the restriction of
$\mathcal{A}$ to the set $α = \{β : β < α\}$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathcal{A}$. Then $C$ is a club. (I proved this part).

Now, in the structure $\mathcal{A}$, the elements are countable ordinals. Suppose
that for each $α ∈ C$, there is some $β < α$ such that $\operatorname{tp}_{\mathcal{A}}(α)$ = $\operatorname{tp}_{\mathcal{A}}(β)$.

Show that some fixed type is realized by uncountably many elements.

I have an inkling that this should follow from a well-known theorem, but don't know what the theorem is and how the proof might go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The well-known theorem you're looking for is [Fodor's lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma).

Comment: Can you find any regressive function with domain $C$?

Comment: I am not sure, is the idea to map C to the universe of A? But I am not sure if this is a regressive function.

Comment: @Linus: It seems like you're just trying to put together "random words" to make sense with your idea. Take a breath, step back, look at your question again. The answer is *right there*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I tried, but I still don't see it. The reason I suggested mapping C to the universe of A was because I proved that C is a club and hence a stationary set which is one of the conditions of Fodor's Theorem. Would you be so kind to help me out?

Comment: @Linus: Literally the third paragraph in your question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I still don't see how Fodor's Theorem ties in. I can't define a regressive function with domain C. (As you said I am probably just missing something really simple or just being really stupid right now).

Comment: @Linus: Unless this is something that you have to submit in half an hour, I suggest that you go for a walk, watch some senseless YouTube videos, go and watch Avengers: Infinity War, do something else. The mind is like a muscle. Yours currently has too much lactic acid from overworking. You need to relax it a little bit, and let the natural process of clearing up your mind do their thing.

Comment: You need to define a function $f\colon C\to\omega_1$ such that for all $\alpha$ in $C$, $f(\alpha)<\alpha$. Where are you going to get some $\beta<\alpha$...?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you. Ah, I got it. I can't believe I am being so dumb. It was right there staring at me in the face. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Linus1234 You're welcome. If you're satisfied with answer, you can accept it by clicking the little green check mark on the left.